# How to move a View inside onDependentViewChanged in a CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to implment a custom Behavior for an ImageView inside a CoordinatorLayout. To be more precise, I want to move the ImageView to the Toolbar when the user scrolls the main content of the Activity and the AppBarLayout is collapsing.
I created my Behavior inside a class that extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior and implemented the method:

```
@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, ImageView child, View dependency) {
```

With some math I compute the values of the x and y coordinates (which are correct) and then I try to move the ImageView with this code:

```
        child.setX(currentX);
    child.setY(currentY);
```

Although the coordinates are correct (according to the Logcat panel), when I expand the AppBarLayout the ImageView appears and disappears apparently in random locations?
What's the problem? 
Do I have to override the onLayoutChild method? And, if so, how?

Comment: After a few tests I found out that the problem arises because I also resize the ImageView while moving with the following code:         
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = (int) currentSize;
        lp.height = (int) currentSize;
        child.setLayoutParams(lp);

Comment: I recorded a short video that shows the problem (the coordinates are correct): https://youtu.be/0TMLzvz2peo

Comment: From the video I can see that after you scroll down the view is scaled back to normal and comes from negative x values. Are you changing `ImageView` parent somehow?